# Group page not showing some members name from Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Could someone explain to me why a few of my members from my group page have blank data for their names but their Facebook ID shows up just fine?

An example of what I am talking about would be:

```
<user>
<id>xxxxxxxx</id>
<name>Bobby Bushay</name>
</user>
```

And the ones that show the fb id but not the name look like this:

```
<user>
<id>xxxxxxxxxxxx</id>
<name> </name>
</user>
```

So I figure it has something to do with their privacy settings maybe? If so, where would I need to direct them in order to change that privacy setting so it can be read? Oddly enough though when I am using the Facebook Graph API Explorer and I click on their ID it gives me all their info **including** their first and last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you go to the User's profile page? E.g. facebook.com/{profile_id}

Its could be that those users are preventing their information being shared to the group / or members of it.

Ask the user to edit the `How people bring your info to apps they use` settings on their account, found under `Privacy Settings` > `Apps, games and websites`. Maybe that will make a difference. In particular, check if the `Bio` checkbox is checked.

Comment: Hum well i just checked out my privacy settings and i do not even have "bio" checked. I only have "my website", "if im online" & "my app activity".

Comment: So this would explain why some users' data isn't coming through. They might have the `Bio` option unchecked too.